# embedded c correct data type for storing an address

Tags: c, embedded

On an embedded 32 bit mcu, what would be the correct data type to store an address? I am reading code which is part of a menu which allows users to examine the contents of memory by specifying the  address. The variable `address` is declared as an `unsigned int`. Is that best practice?

```
  #define MemoryRead(A) (*(volatile unsigned long*)(A))

  int debug monitor(void) {

  unsigned int address, value;

  for (;;) {
  ch = getchar();

address = 0;

if (('0' <= ch && ch <= '9') || {
  putchar(ch);
  printf("\r\nAddress in hex> ");
  address = getnum();
  printf("Address = ");
  printf("%x\r\n",address);
}

switch(ch & 0x7f) {
  case '1':
     value = MemoryRead(address);
     printf("%x\r\n",value);
     break;
```

}

Comment: The correct type for an address would be a pointer of the type the address is pointing to.

Comment: That is not related to the word-width of the CPU. And for printing a pointer value, read the man-page of `printf`. `%x` is definitively wrong.

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no guarantee that a pointer is the same size as an int, although for 32 bit architectures it is a near certainty.

The best type to use to hold an address as an integer type is `uintptr_t` which is defined in `stdint.h` That's guaranteed to be long enough to hold an address.

The best type to hold a generic pointer as is is `void*`.

If you use `uintptr_t` or an actual pointer i.e. `void*`, your `printf` format specifier for the address should be `%p`

In your code, the correct format specifier for printing the result of MemoryRead which is an `unsigned long` is `%lx`.

Comment: It is only guaranteed for `(u)intptr_t` to store a `void *` in it and assign back to a `void *` unchanged. There is no guarantee about printing the value or otherwise manipulating it.

Comment: The code asks for a bit more. OP reads an address value (which is problematic at best already), and prints it.

Comment: Hi folks, I've added the full code to the OP. The code works as in it lets you examine the contents of a memory location but I just want to understand the best practice and if you could demonstrate how a pointer should be used in this case that would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Converting to `uintptr_t` is the most correct answer that can be given.

Comment: @Lundin: If we take the title being the question, the first comment is correct: using a pointer to an appropriate type would be.